# How to observe LiveData of a ViewModel that is not initialized during init / constructor (Room suspend function)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

My `ViewModel` loads data via `Room` in a coroutine:

```
// ViewModel:
lateinit var items : LiveData<List<Item>>
    private set

init {
    viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
        items = MyDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).itemsDao.getAllItems()
    }
}

// Fragment:
viewModel.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    it?.let {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
})
```

This leads to

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property items has not been initialized
```

I understand this error - the `Fragment` tries to access the `items` property before the coroutine is finished, fine.

But how do I solve this? How do I observe the data of a `ViewModel` that is actually provided by a coroutine at a later point in time? Note that I want my query `itemsDao.getAllItems()` to remain a suspend function (no UI freezing).

Comment: So `getAllItems()` returns a `LiveData`? Why are you doing `viewModelScope.launch(IO)` at all if your `getAllItems()` is returning a `LiveData`? `LiveData` returning Dao methods don't need to be run on any dispatcher.

Comment: Ian, thank you. There was no special reason, I am new to it and indeed mixed up some things. It works fine without adding another coroutine scope. Please post as answer. Do you know which coroutine scope the `LiveData` retuning methods use internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `viewModelScope.launch(IO)` at all when using a Dao method that returns a `LiveData` - returning a `LiveData` does not actually query the database at all until you start to `observe()` the `LiveData` (at which point it uses the internal only [ArchTaskExecutor](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:arch/core-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/arch/core/executor/ArchTaskExecutor.java) to run the query off the main thread).

Therefore there's no reason to use a `lateinit var` at all here. You can simply set the `LiveData` directly:

```
val items = MyDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).itemsDao.getAllItems()
```

You should also strongly consider extending [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel), which gives you an `Application` context in the constructor rather than relying on `MyApplication.getContext()`.

Comment: well explained and I will also switch to `AndroidViewModel`, thank you. About the `ArchTaskExecutor`: when I navigate away from a `Fragment` and the query is still running, will it continue or will it be canceled?

Comment: Yeah, pending work gets cleaned up when the observer (i.e., your fragment) is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MediatorLiveData` which is created at viewmodel initialization. Then add your main `LiveData` as source to it.

```kotlin
val items = MediatorLiveData<List<Item>>()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
        val dbItems = MyDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).itemsDao.getAllItems()
        items.addSource(dbItems) { items.postValue(it) }
    }
}
```

More explanation in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData):

> LiveData subclass which may observe other LiveData objects and react on OnChanged events from them.
> This class correctly propagates its active/inactive states down to source LiveData objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch a lot of items. I think you can try to `emit` the livedata like this [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines).

ViewModel:

```
fun items(): LiveData<List<Item>> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(MyDatabase.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()).itemsDao.getAllItems())
}
```

Fragment:

```
viewModel.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    it?.let {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
})
```